Using Gevent PyWSGI with NGINX without an extra WSGI server
This question really doesn't let me sleep well as I want to know exact answer without general warnings without explanation.
My question in general is such: if I use NGINX to proxy Gevent.PyWSGI server - is it enough? Are there any downsides? Gevent documentation says:

This server is intended primarily for development and testing, and secondarily for other “safe” scenarios where it will not be exposed to potentially malicious input. The code has not been security audited, and is not intended for direct exposure to the public Internet. For production usage on the Internet, either choose a production-strength server such as gunicorn, or put a reverse proxy between gevent and the Internet.

Does it mean that putting it under reverse proxy with solve all concerns about safety?
So my setup right now is:

Docker container #1: Python (Flask + Gevent + SocketIO (simple-websocket)) -> Gunicorn (-k gevent)
Docker container #2: NGINX.

Currently I scale my app using Gunicorn, but I don't like Gunicorn websockets implementation since it's not a 100% supported feature of it and I don't like that I have unclear dirty hacks to make it work in my architecture. I wanted to go with uWSGI, but I don't like it's complex nature for that simple purpose (just running Python).
I would understand effort setting up uWSGI or some similar staff in case I wanted to expose it directly to the Internet or I needed scaling my app using this WSGI layer only. BUT. I can use Docker Swarm for that or other external load balancers that do such things much better than Gunicorn.
So could someone please explain what are benefits of running Flask app under extra WSGI server, if in the end it's proxied with NGINX and scaled with Docker or k8s?
